# Autodecode &#x98; encoded values in XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have a C# app that makes a call out to a cold fusion web service (well it resembles a web service). This service returns 1252 encoded XML format, and characters passed a certain range come encoded like this: `&#x98;`. That is one of the characters that actually comes back. I know the actual text value for this is "˜" in codepage 1252 because I can see the value in the original format in the database.

I take the raw XML from the service and feed it into an XmlTextReader like this:

```
// turn our raw xml into a reader
byte[] responseBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rawXml);
MemoryStream responseStream = new MemoryStream(responseBytes);
state.XmlResponseReader = XmlTextReader.Create(
    responseStream,
    new XmlReaderSettings { IgnoreWhitespace = true });
```

Further down I call `state.XmlResponseReader.Read()`. When I do these hex encoded values are removed from the text entirely. So the following text: `"&#x98;hi there"` will show up as "hi there". I want to get "~hi there".

I have tried quite a few different things to try and get these values to get decoded into their text equivalent but nothing has worked.

Manually I can get the correct value by taking the hex value (98), converting it to decimal (152). then doing this: `Encoding.GetEncoding(1252).GetString(new byte[] {152})`. However, that being entirely manual is less desireable. Does anyone know of a way I can get this converted using more streamlined functionality in the .Net framework?

Comment: 1) If you know it's codepage 1252, then why are you using UTF8? 2) Don't use `XmlTextReader.Create`. Use `XmlReader.Create`

Comment: the output from XmlReader.Create can't be cast to an XmlTextReader.

Comment: You shouldn't use XmlTextReader at all, not since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have changed it for posterity sake but it didn't fix the problem I'm having.

Comment: What about my first question? If you know it's codepage 1252, then why are you using UTF8?

Comment: I know that *this* call returns 1252 (at least in some fields) but this code is part of the core to a framework we use for communicating with this web service. Sometimes the messages it receives may not be 1252. Decoding it as UTF8 has ensured that regardless of the encoding, we are able to preserve the original data.

Comment: By the way, you can avoid converting from hex to decimal by simply specifying the hex value: `new byte[] { 0x98 }`.

Comment: ah, that's right. Thanks pickpypg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I didn't find a way to get the XmlTextReader to autodecode the data but I did find the next best thing. Using ReadChars (which isn't available on XmlReader) I was able to retrieve the data from the InnerText of my XML node without having those characters corrupted resulting in loss of data.

Here is my code:

```
int readCharacters = 0;
short bufferSize = 40;
char[] buffer = new char[bufferSize];
StringBuilder innerString = new StringBuilder();

do
{
    readCharacters = reader.ReadChars(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    innerString.Append(buffer, 0, readCharacters);

} while (readCharacters != 0);
```

This allows me to get back my raw data example(`&#x97;&#x98;`) at which point I can manually take 97 and 98 out of that string, convert them to a decimal, then to an ascii character. So the solution is still at least 1/2 manual but the ReadChars has saved me some up front whole-string manipulation that would have otherwise been necessary to facilitate the manual steps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Server.Decode on the value? see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hwzhtkke.aspx

Comment: I couldn't get Server.Decode to compile in my project (it's not asp.net) but I did try System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(reader.Value). Which didn't make a difference.